What is the best approach for managing an old sprawling grapevine that was recently pruned back?
We have a grapevine that has grown wild (unpruned) for years. It has produced grapes decently, but ultimately became unmanageable, so we pruned it back aggressively, back to the thick branches of the stalk. This year, it has now produced considerable new growth--leafy tendrils all over the place; however, as of the end of July, I do not see any clusters forming. I am looking for advice as to what might be best to do at this point--if any additional pruning might help, or what the best approach is going forward. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Pictures and your location please
